# Setting the value of prompt to current date

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

How do you possibly set the value of a prompt(date) to the current date when the user does not input any value? I always get invalid datatype error no matter what I do. :(

This is my prompt:
[image]

Maybe my format is wrong but I have tried, NVL, setting default value on prompt settings and always get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering %Date as the default value.

It should populate the prompt with the current date when the query is executed. 
 You will also need to uncheck the "optional" flag, as a prompt with a default value cannot be optional.

Answer (score 0):

On the criteria, you should define an expression as a decode (since you are on oracle), like this:

```
EFFDT = DECODE(:3,' ', SYSDATE,:3)
```